# Ubuntu Terminal "Shortcut-Key"

Tags: command-line, 13.10

I just changed the "Short-Keys" in Ubuntu. I set <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> for Copy. My fault ... so now I can't use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> for killing the process in the terminal. But it is necessary for me to do this.

How can I change the shortcut key? Maybe so that <kbd>Esc</kbd> is for killing the process, or some other combination?

Comment: Control+Shift+C (and V) are the copy-paste defaults for the terminal. I'd just set those back up if I were you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> has nothing to do with the graphical environment, it is a much more basic command and involves sending a particular signal ([SIGINT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGINT_%28POSIX%29)).

These can't really be modified by the user. I mean they can, but you would need to modify the source of `/usr/src/$(uname -r)/include/linux/signal.h` and recompile your kernel probably.

Just don't use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> for copy.

Comment: I found a command that i have to exec to allow Ctrl + C for Copy. So i overwritten the Ctr + C default command. I just want to - if possible - reoverwrite this or use another shortcut key.

Comment: @TimoRütten I know, I am trying to explain that it is not possible without modifying your kernel's code (well, associated files) and recompiling. This is not controlled by the graphical environment, you will have to use a different shortcut for Copy because Ctrl+C is already taken (and was already taken _long_ before it became Copy).

Comment: @TimoRütten I am trying to explain that this has nothing to do with your terminal, it is a kernel function and not supposed to be changed by users. If you happen to be comfortable modifying source code you _could_ try it but it is 1) going to be VERY complex unless you know what you're doing and 2) not really worth the effort.

Comment: The command i used was smth like "gconftool-2 -t str -s /apps/gnome-terminal/keybindings/copy "<Control>c"" - not this complex i think. I just need to know how to overwrite it again so that i can use CTRL+C again for killing the process.

Comment: @TimoRütten yes, I understand. I am trying to tell you that the Ctrl+C in the terminal is COMPLETELY different. The `gconftool` is interacting with the graphical interface, the terminal's Ctrl+C has absolutely nothing to do with that and is at least 20 years older. It is not something from the "terminal" as you seem to think but something of the Linux kernel, completely separate from any windows you see on your screen.

Comment: Now i understood. Thanks. I rewrite the comand for copy. Now everything works fine. I can kill the process again. (: